# I want to get Watch History of User at youtube after He/She login at my website

Tags: youtube

I want to get Watch History of User at youtube after He/She login at my website and when i am trying this API V3 I am unable to get data with this request .

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I think so i am unable to pass the user channel thing i don't know where to pass that and what to pass please let me know when user loged in at my website with google account and i have these permission :

```
$client->addScope("email");
$client->addScope("profile");
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit');
```

can i get watch list and how ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quick question: Are you literally using the request URL above where it says "{YOUR_API_KEY}" in it? If so, you need to get a Google API key and plug it in there. You may have other issues beyond that, but if you don't have a real API key there, that's part of the problem.

Comment: no i am using API key and i just pasted this for not to show here ....

Comment: Reference Link : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Comment: Good, then sadly I'm at the limit of my knowledge on this one. I've called other Google APIs but not the YouTube related ones.

Answer (score 0):

A Youtube API team member said [here](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2012/01/watch-history-comes-to-api_24.html) in 2012 about the watch history data

`This feed allows authenticated API users to retrieve their own YouTube viewing histories—retrieving the watch history of any other user is not allowed.`

Thus you can only retrieve the watch history of your own profile.

I find this disappointing. I haven't found any information that this has changed since 2012, but perhaps the potential of its use (to make online apps specialized for viewing preferences of the user), could have changed this.